# jQuery .load function refuses to work

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, localhost

Background: Using Linux (Fedora 22), running apache server on localhost. jquery.min.js (3.1.0) in js/ subdirectory at top level, copied from Internet. Other jQuery functions seem to work fine.
Example shown from *jQuery in action, third edition, page 267 (Loading content into elements)*.
I am attempting to plug in content (text) from a file to a `<div>` element as this is a function I am working on elsewhere using a drop-down menu. However, as a NOOB to jQuery, I am attempting to get simple things to work first. This particular problem has me stumped. Two different load functions to perform the same thing, the first works (using Ajax XHR), the second (using jQuery) refuses. Here is the entire body listing:

```
<body>
  <div id="elem"></div>
  <hr width="40%">
  <div id="contain"></div>
  <script>
     var xhr;
     if (window.ActiveXObject) {
        xhr = new ActiveXObject('Microsoft.XMLHTTP');
     } else if (window.XMLHttpRequest) {
        xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
     } else {
        throw new Error('Ajax is not supported by this browser');
     }

     xhr.onreadystatechange = function() {
        if (this.readyState === 4) {
           if (this.status >= 200 && this.status < 300) {
              document.getElementById('elem').innerHTML = this.responseText;
           }
        }
     };

     xhr.open('GET', 'some-resource');
     xhr.send();
  </script>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="//localhost/js/jquery.min.js">
     jQuery("#contain").load('some-resource');
  </script>
</body>
```

I have placed both methods in same "script" container; and as here, different containers. Neither makes a difference. Scripts are at the end, so "div" elements exist.
Console messages as follows:

```
GET https://localhost/...listing.10.3.html [HTTP/1.1 304 Not Modified 15ms]
GET https://localhost/js/jquery.min.js [HTTP/1.1 200 OK 0ms]
XHR https://localhost/...some-resource [HTTP/1.1 304 Not Modified 0ms]
```

So, is there some jQuery functionality I am missing for a "localhost" setup, or is there some silly thing I have left out, a dot or comma? I have not tried this on a hosted server as I wish to test before that stage. Any insights would be most appreciated.
Edit: This in another exercise, works fine. Will have to decipher it to see the real difference:

> $('#boot-chooser-control')
>         .load('actions/fetch-boot-style-options.php')
>         .change(function(event) {
>            $('#product-detail-pane').load(
>              'actions/fetch-product-details.php',
>          {
>             model: $(event.target).val()
>          },
>          function() {
>            $('[value=""]', event.target).remove();
>          }
>        );
>      });

Placed the jquery load both in the head, and separately just above the line in question. Neither made a difference.

Comment: you can't put javascript inside a script tag that has a src attribute. well, you can, but it wont run,as you've seen see [MDN documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/HTML/Element/script#attr-src)- put your jquery code in another script tag AFTER the one that loads jquery - better yet, you probably should load jquery in a script tag in the page HEAD rather than BODY

Comment: Well, have tried it both ways: in the head, and as a separate entry just above the script. Neither makes any difference. However, in a further exercise, the same function works okay. Such as this:

Comment: So I placed the script source in the header. That didn't work. However, I also changed the double-quotes around the function to single quotes. That did the trick! So now the "#contain" is '#contain' and that works. Thanks for the help! It's always the little things that are hard to find.

Comment: that should **not** make a difference - something else happened when you changed the quotes - perhaps you didn't update the file when you thought you did before, because seriously, there is no difference between `'` and `"` in this scenario - change them back and see for yourself

Comment: However, as a side note, I just now changed the quotes back, and it still works, so that is not the real reason it decided to work. Perhaps it took the day off yesterday. :-) Which brings me back to the "script in the head" answer #1 above.